# Kyocera C6750 Hydro Elite not listed adb devices

Tags: android, adb

I am new to android development and have just purchased a Kyocera c6750 Hydro Elite. It's brand new just out of the box. I am having trouble getting it to list under devices when running ./adb devices, it doesn't show any device.

```
 ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ sudo ./adb devices
 List of devices attached
```

There is nothing listed. I should mention I am running Ubuntu 12.10 if this matters?

It is shown as being connected when running lsusb and appears to be mounted ok. 
Here is the output:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0482:f001 Kyocera Corp.
```

Also It doesn't seem to matter if I change connectivity from mass storage or media sync mode as far as what files and folder are displayed under the mounted drive. Maybe this is normal, my Galaxy S4 displays lots of folders and files for media and documents, etc...

I have everything up to date on my pc, has anyone else had this problem is there a solution? I have searched hi and low to find little or no help.

Comment: If you have not already done so, you need to enable the developer menu and enable USB debugging.  You also need a udev rule as described in the developer docs, but without that the device should be listed but as inaccessible.  Then you may need to add the VID (0482) to your ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and kill and restart adb.

Comment: I have developer mode enabled, and have created a rules file under /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules I dont see a adb_usb.ini file under the ~android-sdk-linux dir. Can i just create the file? My galaxy list just fine btw.

Comment: No, it is ~/.android/adb_usb.ini - ie, under your home directory, not the sdk directory.  It is not needed for certain well-known manufacturer ID's which adb knows about by default.

Comment: oh ok I just noticed it forgot to show hidden dir ctrl+h.

Comment: What do I place in the ini file I added a line like this 0x0482 or is there more to is than that?

Comment: That will probably do it, hopefully with a newline at the end.  Now kill and restart adb

Comment: Awesome!! It's now displaying! Thank you so much for helping me with this!